# Programming Strategy for ASP.NET MVC 5 - Updating a Child or Related Records on Same Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am struggling a bit with strategies that allow for updating child records related to a parent record in MVC in the same view. Take for instance model classes described below.

```
 public class Person {
   public Person() {}
   int personId{get;set;}
   string personName{get;set}
   public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
  }
  public class Phone {
    public Phone() {}
    public int PhoneId {get;set;}
    public string PhoneType {get;set;}
    public  string Number {get;set;}
    public string Ext {get;set;}
  }
```

Providing a single page view allows for Creating,Updating,Deleting a person easily.

Adding actions that jump to views designed specifically for the phone records and then return the user to the person record is also straightforward.

*What is the best strategy for displaying the related phone records for the person in the same view as the person information and allowing for the CRUD operations to be used against only the phone entities in the same view?*

If the answer is that AJAX is the best approach then that is perfectly acceptable. I am looking for feedback from the community that describes what individuals have used in this type scenario in their projects that have this type of challenge.

There was one approach listed here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786085/ASP-NET-MVC-List-Editor-with-Bootstrap-Modals

That had a decent if somewhat cumbersome approach.

I have to believe that this is a much simpler problem and that I am quite literally missing the obvious.

Comment: I like to use ajax for this reason. With ajax you can post entities with lists of children and it will work pretty well. However I usually also have separate controllers for the children because trying to PUT or DELETE based on the contents of a child list tends to be awkward and inefficient.

Comment: I completely agree with your logic. I am wondering it is usually speaking the industry standard approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done in-line editing by displaying the current phone information and having hidden inputs.  When the user clicks the edit button, I toggle visibility to hide the display and show the inputs.

I've also done similar to the article.  Have a modal popup to edit phone numbers, after saving the changes and closing the modal refresh the partial with the phone number list.

In either scenario I'm just submitting an ajax request and return a partial that I use to replace the div that contained the original information.

The modal dialog seems to be little more "modern".

Comment: I really appreciate this. So far one comment and one answer and both suggest ajax. Unless there is strong disagreement by tomorrow, I would accept ajax as the standard. There are a few problems with the solution in the link, teh replacecontent div can only be replaced once and if the reload content includes action links an event has to fire on the modal hide or hidden events to re-attach the modal trigger event.

Comment: Yeah, replacing a div does cause some issues.  Basically in my js ready I have call InitializeDiv.  InitializeDiv then does an unbind/bind        btnMyButton.unbind("click").click(function () {